# Understanding Schema.org in Stack Overflow

Tags: html, semantic-web, schema.org, microdata

If you inspect my name at the bottom of this post you'll see:

```html
<div class="user-details" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
```

What are the possible benefits for adding those attributes (`itemtype`/`itemprop`)?

Comment: Are you asking about the benefits of using these attributes _in general_? Or specifically about the benefits of applying them to the user details element on a Stack Overflow post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used for SEO.

> Most webmasters are familiar with HTML tags on their pages. Usually,
>   HTML tags tell the browser how to display the information included in
>   the tag. For example,
>
> ## Avatar
>
> tells the browser to display the
>   text string "Avatar" in a heading 1 format. However, the HTML tag
>   doesn't give any information about what that text string
>   means—"Avatar" could refer to the hugely successful 3D movie, or it
>   could refer to a type of profile picture—and this can make it more
>   difficult for search engines to intelligently display relevant content
>   to a user.
>
> **> Schema.org provides a collection of shared vocabularies webmasters can
>   use to mark up their pages in ways that can be understood by the major
>   search engines: Google, Microsoft, Yandex and Yahoo!**
>
> You use the schema.org vocabulary along with the Microdata, RDFa, or
>   JSON-LD formats to add information to your Web content. This guide
>   will help get you up to speed with Microdata and schema.org so that
>   you can start adding markup to your web pages.

Source: https://schema.org/docs/gs.html

Also, the `itemprop` attribute is a global one and used to add properties to an item.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop